# Internal name encoding in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

It's pretty well publicised knowledge that `_x0020_` replaces spaces in SharePoint internal field names. When working with SharePoint web services this can be a bit of a nightmare until you write a replace rule when comparing field names.

I've just found myself another one of these "encoding exceptions" in a field called SSL2. Bizarrely the internal name ends out being `_x0053_SL2`. I've tried something like RRL2 which comes out as `_x0052_`. From this it appears that the number used in the encoding represents the ASCII value of that character. Space would likewise be `_x0020_`.

**My question is twofold:**

1. **In this case, whats causing SharePoint to encode these
   characters.**
2. **Broadly, what sort of encoding is being done and is there a general
       step I can do to decode strings
       rather than replacing specific
       occurances which I've come across
       and know to be a problem.**

Answer (score 8):

You should use System.Xml.XmlConvert.DecodeName

Comment: This doesn't encode unicode characters like `ąłỳść`. Look at @SalientBrain answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I wanted to understand the first part of this question and it wasn't answered so here goes...

Essentially `SSL2` is being encoded to `_x0053_SL2` because it resembles an "A1 mode" excel cell reference (`[a-zA-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{1,5}`). When Sharepoint sees one of those it decides it needs to encode the first character.

This is obviously not standard XML encoding, and I'm not going to posit any theories as to why this is done, but hopefully this at least explains what the OP observed.

Comment: can you please give us more details on this issue?  how do you solve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's a secret) :

```
public static string EncodeName(string name)
{
    var encodedName = string.Empty;
    foreach (var c in name)
    {
        var s = c.ToString();
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(s);
        //Regex.Match(s, "[^\x00-\x80]")
        //IsCyrillic (0x400–0x4FF) и IsCyrillicSupplement (0x500–0x52F)
        //if (Regex.Match(s, @"\p{IsCyrillic}|\p{IsCyrillicSupplement}").Success)
        if (!Regex.Match(s, @"[a-zA-Z0-9_]").Success)
        {
            encodedName += "_x";
            foreach (var b in bytes)
            {
                encodedName += b.ToString("X2").ToLowerInvariant();
            }
            encodedName += "_";
        }
        else
        {
            encodedName += s;
        }
    }
    if (encodedName.Length > 32)
    {
        encodedName = encodedName.Substring(0, 32);
    }
    return encodedName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint XML encodes names because it want to be able to use the field names as attributes in XML.

You can use System.Xml.XmlConvert.EncodeName to encode your names

Comment: Doesn't work. Putting SSL2 into EncodeName comes out with SSL_x005F_x0020_2. Not the _x0053_SL_x0020_2 that SharePoint uses.