# SharePoint rest query returns (400) Bad Request when used with encoded field names

Tags: rest, sharepoint, unicode, encoding

It is a known behavior that SharePoint encodes the first letter of column names on some occasions:

[Internal name encoding in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600647/internal-name-encoding-in-sharepoint)

and also:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43342/curious-internal-name-unicode-encoding-behavior

The problem I am facing is that whenever I use an update rest query involving such column, I receive a "(400) Bad Request". With $select query I get "The field or property does not exist."

I am trying with "Col1", "_x0043_ol1" or "%5Fx0043%5Fol1" and the requests are still failing.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this one?

Comment: find all the items in REST and look at the response in chrome or IE and look at the internal name. What it shows is exactly how you need to have it in your REST call

Comment: Exactly! As it looks like the name should have prefix "OData_". In my case it became "OData__x0043_ol1".

Thanks a lot, @Mike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all the items in REST and look at the response in chrome or IE and look at the internal name. What it shows is exactly how you need to have it in your REST call. It's possible that the internal names aren't being referenced in your REST call.